# Distinguishing RPi4 models with USB-C issue and without

Tags: pi-4

The first model of the RPi4 seems to have an issue with USB-C, as [reported by ArsTechnica](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/07/raspberry-pi-4-uses-incorrect-usb-c-design-wont-work-with-some-chargers/) in July 2019. The effect is that E-marked cables do not work well.

The Raspberry Foundation has confirmed this issue and wanted to provide a fixed variant in "next few months". That was in July 2019 and a few months are over, so I wonder whether I could distinguish "old" RPi 4 models from "new" RPi4 models.

How do I distinguish RPi4 boards with USB-C issue from the same model with USB-C issue fixed?

Comment: I would've thought the PCB itself would have the revision number written on it

Comment: @JaromandaX: yes, like on previous models like 3B or 3B+ it simply was on the silk screen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Revision 1.2 seems to contain the USB-C fix. Raspberry Pi 4 models with the fix have reached the market. The difference can be found in hardware and software.

Regarding the hardware identification, it's easiest to see near the SD card:

[image: RPi4 rev 1.1 versus 1.2]

For software, the Raspberry Foundation [lists Revisions for the RPi 4 rev 1.2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/revision-codes/README.md) like this:

> ```
> b03112    4B  1.2     2GB     Sony UK
> c03112    4B  1.2     4GB     Sony UK
> ```

Raspbian kernels seem to be [fixed since end of November 2019](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flash-kernel/+bug/1854487).

Thus the output of

```
dmesg | grep "Pi 4 Model B Rev"
```

should result in

```
[0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1
```

or

```
[0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2
```

Comment: or simply `grep "^Model" /proc/cpuinfo`